# How do I receive the Rannoch: Admiral Koris mission?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I'm looking for the "Rannoch: Admiral Koris" mission. **Who or what do I need to interact with to receive this mission?** I know it's possible to permanently miss certain missions by not accessing them before completing other missions. Is this the case with "Rannoch: Admiral Koris", or am I just not wandering around in the right places?

Comment: If you're trying to broker peace in this scenario, also note that on the rescue mission for the Admiral, you've got to make sure he survives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll get this mission at the same time you get Rannoch: Geth Fighters.  If you haven't advanced the plot to this point, you won't have this mission.  This happens *after* you've assaulted the Geth Dreadnought.

Note that it is important to play the Admiral Koris mission, and the other side mission on Rannoch (Geth Fighters) *before* completing Priority: Rannoch, as it's possible that the outcome of Priority: Rannoch will be influenced by whether or not you've completed these two missions.  Completing *either* of these two missions will unlock access to Priority: Rannoch.

Answer (score 0):

You get this from the admiral in the War Room after the Geth Dreadnaught mission.

[Here is a G4 walk through of the mission.](http://www.g4tv.com/videos/57668/mass-effect-3-rannoch-admiral-koris-walkthrough-video/)